# Keys.SHIFT works fine in Mac but not in Windows using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, windows-10-desktop

This code snippet works fine in Mac but not in Windows.

```
actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(comp5).click(comp6).click(comp7).click(comp8).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Any alternatives which works in both env. in Selenium? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems instead of `keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)` and `keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)` you need to use **`keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)`** and **`keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)`**. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(comp5).click(comp6).click(comp7).click(comp8).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another alternative. Let me try this one as well.